# ValueError (string to float), Conditional For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have my data in a `pandas.groupby` object and am attempting iterate through the groups based on a conditional in column titled "Amount". However, the error message I'm getting is trying to convert a "Reference" code from a string to a float, but I'm unsure where I'm giving this directive.

```
for data in row:
    if float(data) in ['Amount'] > 0:
        {'buy_currency' : ['Currency'],
          'buy_quantity' : ['Amount'],
        'order_id' : str(data)['Reference']}
```

I believe I am misunderstanding the second line: `if float(data) in ['Amount'] > 0`

I only want to convert the "Amount" fields to a float, and am OK with other fields remaining strings.

I appreciate any guidance or a nudge in the right direction!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
mask = df2.groupby(['Reference'])
groups = mask.groups

for ref, trades in mask:
    for index, row in trades.iterrows():
       for data in row:
                if float(data) in ['Amount'] > 0:
                    {'buy_currency' : ['Currency'],
                     'buy_quantity' : ['Amount'],
                     'order_id' : str(data)['Reference']}
                else:
                    {'sell_currency' : ['Currency'],
                     'buy_quantity' : ['Amount'],
                     'order_id': str(data)['Reference']}
```

The dataset contains the following samples:
[Dataset Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w4rD.png)

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'bbb8ee04-053c-4174-b5b1-281c10618d52'
```

Comment: Can you please try to provide a value for data so that the problem can be recreated. Maybe just look at the head of your data frame and see if the problem still occurs? so this code should include `data = pd.DataFrame({...})` so that someone checking it can easily recreate the error

Comment: Is `data` the groupby object? Your conditional is checking if a list is greater than 0 which isn’t a valid comparison. You probably want to check if your values in the amount column are greater than 0.

Comment: Hi Robert and Jack,

I've edited my initial post with some additional information. I apologize for not providing all the details from the outset. I'm sure this is a very elementary question for many, but appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Hey buddy! What would be really helpful to the experts here if you could post your raw data then your expected outcome along with your attempts, that's the expected formally at SO.

Comment: @JackMoody I initially had it written this way, but receive the same error message in both instances:
```
 for data in row:
                if (float(data)["Amount"]) > 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do. Did you know that you can check multiple columns values in one go using `masks` in pandas? Here's some sample code that maybe useful to you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
df2['Amount'] = df2['Amount'].astype(float)
df2['Reference'] = df2['Reference'].astype(str)

# no need to group
mask = df2['Amount'] > 0
df2['buy_currency'] = np.where(mask, df2['Currency'], np.nan)
df2['buy_quantity'] = np.where(mask, df2['Amount'], np.nan)
df2['order_id'] = np.where(mask, df2['Reference'], np.nan)

mask2 = df2['Amount'] < 0
df2['sell_currency'] = np.where(mask2, df2['Currency'], np.nan)
df2['sell_quantity'] = np.where(mask2, df2['Amount'], np.nan)
df2['order_id'] = np.where(mask2, df2['Reference'], np.nan)
```